# Symfony 2.3/2.4 Standalone Form Component

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I am trying to use the Symfony 2.3 Form Standalone component to use outside of Symfony Framework.

I tried the following url http://n.clavaud.free.fr/blog/index.php?article31/symfony2-standalone-form-component-tutorial

in the above url code good but it is based on the old versions of symfony framework.

I am getting problems while using Symfony 2.3

I want the code same like above in the url but it should work on Symfony 2.3 or any other suggestions?

I am using below code

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormRendererInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\CoreExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfExtension;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParser;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReference;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\DefaultTranslator;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\FormHelper;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\TranslatorHelper;

// validation
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\StaticMethodLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

/**
 * Load and configure autoloader
 * @see http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/tools/autoloader.html
 */
require_once 'Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->register();
$loader->registerNamespace('Symfony', __DIR__.'/');

/**
 * Parameters
 */
$locale = null;

/**
 * Entity
 */
class Message
{

    public $sender;
    public $recipient;
    public $message;

    // validation
    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('sender', new Constraints\NotBlank());
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('sender', new Constraints\Email());
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('recipient', new Constraints\NotBlank());
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('recipient', new Constraints\Email());
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('message', new Constraints\NotBlank());
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('message', new Constraints\MinLength(10));
    }

}

/**
 * Form Class
 * @see http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes
 */
class MessageType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('sender', 'email')
        ->add('recipient', 'email')
        ->add('message', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'message';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'new\Message',
        );
    }

}

/**
 * Template name parser
 * @see Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Templating\Helper\Fixtures\StubTemplateNameParser
 *
 * Needed to load the templates used for rendering form items.
 */
class StubTemplateNameParser implements TemplateNameParserInterface
{
    private $root;

    private $rootTheme;

    public function __construct($root, $rootTheme)
    {
        $this->root = $root;
        $this->rootTheme = $rootTheme;
    }

    public function parse($name)
    {

        list($bundle, $controller, $template) = explode(':', $name);

        if ($template[0] == '_') {
            $path = $this->rootTheme.'/Custom/'.$template;
        } elseif ($bundle === 'TestBundle') {
            $path = $this->rootTheme.'/'.$controller.'/'.$template;
        } else {
            $path = $this->root.'/'.$controller.'/'.$template;
        }

        return new TemplateReference($path, 'php');

    }
}

/**
 * Create an entity
 */
$message = new Message();
$message->sender = 'mymail@example.com';

/**
 * Build a form from a form factory
 */
/* $form_factory = new FormFactory(array(
                                     new CoreExtension(),
                                     // validation
                                     new ValidatorExtension(
                                         new Validator(
                                             new ClassMetadataFactory(
                                                 new StaticMethodLoader()
                                             ),
                                             new ConstraintValidatorFactory(),
                                             new DefaultTranslator()
                                         )
                                     )
                                ));*/
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$form_factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
               ->addExtension(new CoreExtension())
               ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
               ->getFormFactory();
$form = $form_factory->create(new MessageType(), $message);

/**
 * Create a PHP template engine
 */
$root = realpath(__DIR__ . '/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views');
$rootTheme = realpath(__DIR__ . '/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources');
$templateNameParser = new StubTemplateNameParser($root, $rootTheme);
$loader = new FilesystemLoader(array());
$engine = new PhpEngine($templateNameParser, $loader);

/**
 * This helper will help rendering form items
 */
/*$form_helper = new FormHelper($engine, array(
                                            'FrameworkBundle:Form',
                                       ));*/
$form_helper = new FormHelper(new FormRendererInterface());

/**
 * Bind it to the engine
 */
$engine->setHelpers(array(
                         $form_helper,
                         new TranslatorHelper(new Translator($locale, new MessageSelector())),
                    ));

/**
 * Bind submitted data
 */
$submitted = false;
$valid = null;
if (isset($_POST[$form->getName()])) {
    $form->bind($_POST[$form->getName()]);
    $submitted = true;
    // validation
    if ($valid = $form->isValid()) {
        // you may want to redirect at this state
        $data = $form->getData();
        echo 'validated success';
        var_dump($data);
    }
}

/**
 * Create the form view
 */
$form_view = $form->createView();

/**
 * Now, it's time to render HTML!
 */
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post"
    <?php print $form_helper->enctype($form_view) ?>
      novalidate="novalidate">
    <?php print $form_helper->widget($form_view) ?></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php if ($submitted && $valid) : ?>
    <p><strong>Submitted form is valid.</strong></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<p><em>Message object:</em></p>
<pre><?php print print_r($message, true); ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Form\FormRendererInterface in /var/www/new/test.php on line 193

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Any error message?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to instantiate an interface:

```
$form_helper = new FormHelper(new FormRendererInterface());
```

Interfaces are not classes and you cannot instantiate them (see http://php.net/interface and read something on OOP).

Check out an example of using the form component standalone: https://github.com/bschussek/standalone-forms

Comment: Hi Jakub Zalas,

Thanks for the reply but it is not working and it is following Symfony 2.1

giving the error 

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\DefaultCsrfProvider' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/eeee/src/setup.php on line 26

Comment: Hi,
Any one has update on this?
I tried in diff ways
now i am getting the error
**Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException' with message 'Unable to render the form as none of the following blocks exist: "_message_enctype", "message_enctype", "form_enctype"**

Comment: I just tried bschussek/standaolne-forms and it works (just clone the repo and run composer install - install, not update). It's based on 2.1 and you'll have to figure it out how to update it to the latest version.

Comment: There's actually one small thing you need to fix for 2.3 - in the index.php replace the MinLength with Length. Name of this constraint has change.

Comment: Hi Jakub Zalas, Thanks for the reply. I want to use the PHP as template Engine how can i do it.
Another and my main requirement is building custom field types

Comment: No problem, the repo I recommended you has a branch with PHP templates. Have you tried that? Please do and ask concrete questions about problems you're facing.

Comment: Hi Jakub Zalas, Thank you very much i tried the repo and PHP templates are working.
I need to create Custom Form Field Types like 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html
in standalone forms

Comment: This is a whole new question. I think my answer is satisfactory for your original answer, no? Registering your custom type will require some work on your side (unless you're ready to use the DI component as well). Have a look at how it's organised in the FrameworkBundle. Also, check out the PreloadedExtension.

Comment: Hi Jakub Zalas, is there any update for me on create Custom Form Field Types using standalone forms?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, is there any update on what you've actually tried to solve YOUR problem?

Comment: Yes Jakub Zalas displaying built in field types in php template is working but i need custom field how to implement them using standalone form component

Comment: And what have you tried doing to achieve that? Besides, looks like my answer solved the problem from your question. Don't you think you should mark it as solved?

Comment: Still my problem exists i want to use Standalone Form in Symfony 2.3 version